# Extend Windows Hello with a new authentication method

Tags: windows, authentication, gina, windows-hello

Is there a way to add a new custom authentication method on Windows Hello based on my code?
I saw there is [GINA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/gina) but it's not an API and it's difficult to use with languages different from C++.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

`Windows Hello` assumes `Windows 10`. In this case you must implement a `Credential Provider`.

Have a look at Microsoft Credential Provider API [Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/) and
[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-and-credential-providers)

In this case there are exist solutions to implement the provider using C#.